# Reading an XML array to python dict

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to read an array from an XML data file with the shown structure.
By using [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python) I received the following without my array.

```
<event id="1" settings="183" digitizer="LoremID" timestamp="42">
 <triggershift samples="0"></triggershift>
 <trace channel="0">2 4 1 2 1 23 5 4 2 4 2 
 </trace>
</event>
```

Output:

```
{'id': '1', 
'settings': '183', 
'digitizer': 'LoremID', 
'timestamp': '42', 
'triggershift': {'samples': '0'}, 
'trace': {'channel': '0'}}
```

Does anyone have ideas on how to read both the settings and the array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

content = """<event id="1" settings="183" digitizer="LoremID" timestamp="42">
 <triggershift samples="0"></triggershift>
 <trace channel="0">2 4 1 2 1 23 5 4 2 4 2</trace>
</event>"""

root = ET.fromstring(content)
settings = {**root.attrib}
for el in root:
    settings[el.tag] = {**el.attrib}
    if el.text:
        array = el.text.split(" ")
        settings[el.tag]["value"] = array
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "settings": "183",
    "digitizer": "LoremID",
    "timestamp": "42",
    "triggershift": {
        "samples": "0"
    },
    "trace": {
        "channel": "0",
        "value": [
            "2",
            "4",
            "1",
            "2",
            "1",
            "23",
            "5",
            "4",
            "2",
            "4",
            "2"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Upd.**

If you want to convert `array` elements to `int`, you can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
settings[el.tag]["value"] = list(map(int, array))
```